# Replacing Blogger template with external code

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, blogger

The story is - I'd like to make some changes on my Blogger template but I don't want to do it in a way it could make my readers see what I'm doing.

So, I was thinking about using Greasemonkey or some kind of Firefox add-on to replace all the code in template just for current session and my browser since I'm the one using the script/add-on.

Is there a way to remove all the HTML visible in Bloggers's Template Edit HTML with one I provide in script?

Thanks!

Comment: While, theoretically, Greasemonkey could do this, this would be a major "fool's errand".  Just [create a test blog for your changes](https://www.google.com/search?q=testing+Blogger+templates).

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to create a test blog for experimenting with designs. This is what almost all the webmasters do. You may also use some offline editors such as Adobe Dreamweaver.

Comment: Well, I was hoping to see my new template on user's comments (which I can fake to see what happens) and some widgets connected to databases on other services (which I really can't fake).
However, thanks again!